# MySQL show data from Rows to columns

Tags: mysql, join, pivot

I am stuck at getting a query with joining 2 tables. Below is the database structure.
What I want to achieve is to list all the information from one table with join on the second table but it has 3 conditions. I have written the following SQL but it's not working.I want only 2 rows returning all rows data in each 3 columns.
Please advice.

Tables are:
[image]
[image]

My SQL:

```
SELECT b.*,
       CASE WHEN pc.caster_type = '1' THEN pc.name END as  primary_caster ,
       CASE WHEN pc.caster_type = '2' THEN pc.name END as  secondary_caster ,
       CASE WHEN pc.caster_type = '3' THEN pc.name END as  caster  
FROM broadcasts b 
left join rel_braodcast_casters pc ON pc.fk_broadcast_id = b.broadcast_id ;
```

Getting this result:

[image]

I do not want multiple records for each broadcast. I want to replace NULL values with corresponding rows of data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY broadcast_id`, wrap fields into some aggregate function(MAX, for example). Alternatively - join 3 separate copies of `rel_brodcast_casters` table.

Comment: I tried with Group BY. But then it eliminates records for secondary caster for broadcast id 1 and similarly for others.
And 3 joins query is not working for me. Maybe I have written incorrectly

Comment: Build fiddle, I'll show...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83f530/2/0
This is fiddle

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83f530/6 or http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83f530/7

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer. Below is the fiddle.

sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83f530/6 or sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83f530/7

Thanks to [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina) who helped me a lot. I will prefer to use single join SQL over multiple join fiddle.